# How to use an IObservable<int> to segment an IObservable<T> into an IObservable<T[]> of varying length

Tags: c#, rx.net

I have a "values" `IObservable<T>` which is returning `T` elements which must be combined in sequence into variable-length arrays, and I have a "control" `IObservable<int>` which tells me how long the next array must be.
Dropping an element, repeating it, or getting the results out of order will make the results meaningless.

This is for a serial-connected robotics project I'm rewriting in Rx.NET.

```cs
IObservable<char> values = new [] {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H' }.ToObservable();
IObservable<int> control = new [] { 1, 4, 2 }.ToObservable();
IObservable<char[]> result = control.SelectMany(length => values.Take(length).ToArray());
```

I'd like to see something like this:

```
values  ----A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H-->
control --1-----4---------------2--->
result  ---[A]---------[BCDE]--[FG]->
```

But my attempt so far results in

```
-[A]-[AB]-[ABCD]->
```

Comment: Is it okay/possible that you can define helper subjects which will be triggered/filled by subscriptions from the original observables?

Comment: Absolutely, if it works I'm willing to try it. How might I go about doing that?

Comment: Hmm, I think I have an idea how to go about this, or at least an idea of where to look. I'll tinker and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create several helper subject to prepare/create new observables to build the new observable you want. You can build subjects for these kind of observables:

1. Create a new observable which repeats a unique value the count equal to the number read from `control`. From `(1, 4, 2)` you will get `(guid_1, guid_2, guid_2, guid_2, guid_2, guid_3, guid_3)`. Call this observable `repeatSize`.
2. Use the `Zip()` operator to combine one value each from `repeatSize` and `values`. You will get an observable with the values: `((A,guid_1), (B,guid_2), (C,guid_2), (D,guid_2), (E,guid_2), (F,guid_3), (G,guid_3))`. Call this observable `zippedValues`.
3. Subscribe on `zippedValues` and put/add the original value in a list. Also save the previous value from the `repeatSize` observable. Compare it with the current value of `repeatSize`. When it has been changed (like from `guid_2` to `guid_3`) you know you have reached the end/start, so you can send the filled list to a new observable. After that you reset the list again and begin filling it up again.

You might need to build 2-3 `Subject<T>` objects, subscribe to them and use several `OnNext()` calls to fill them from subscription of other observables.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this out!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's the code which fits all my needs. Progman, you were instrumental in making this work with your advice. Here it is, wrapped up in a tidy `Observable.Create` and turned into an extension method on `IObservable<T>`, with a disposable that disposes of the subscription on the zipped sequence.

```cs
    public static IObservable<T[]> Chop<T>(this IObservable<T> values, IObservable<int> control) =>
        Observable.Create<T[]>(observer => 
        {
            List<T> buffer = new List<T>();
            return values.Zip(control.SelectMany(length => Enumerable.Repeat(length, length)), 
                              (value, length) => (value, length))
                         .Subscribe(next => 
                         {
                             buffer.Add(next.value);
                             if (buffer.Count == next.length)
                             {
                                 observer.OnNext(buffer.ToArray());
                                 buffer.Clear();
                             }
                         });
        });
```

Sample output:

```
values  ----A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--J--K--L--M--N--O--P-->
control --1-4-2-0-3-3--------------------------------------->
result  ---[A]---------[BCDE]-[FG]----[HIJ]----[KLM]-------->
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I believe you can combine `Zip()` and `Scan()` to produce the output you requested.

```
IObservable<char> values = new [] {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H' }.ToObservable();
IObservable<int> control = new [] { 1, 4, 2 }.ToObservable();
IObservable<char[]> result = control.Zip(
    control.Scan(values, (rest, length) => rest.Skip(length)),
    (length, vals) => vals.Take(length).ToArray()
);
```